# Multisite registration form customization

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, multisite

I am trying to customize the registration form on a WP Multisite installation. I've done this successfully in the past on a single site install using the `register_form` hook to add fields to the form, but that hook does not work with multisite. On [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) for `register_form`, there is a note:

WordPress MS Note: For Wordpress MS (Multi-Site), use the 'signup_header' action to redirect users away from the signup.

There is no documentation for `signup_header`, and when I attempt to redirect away from the signup using that hook, I get a "headers already sent" error stemming from the header.php file. For testing purposes, I am using the default theme with no plugins.

```
add_action( 'signup_header', 'test_signup_redirect' );

function test_signup_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( "http://google.com" );
    exit;
}
```

Has anybody successfully customized the registration form on a multisite setup? Does anyone have any insight on the note in the documentation regarding the `signup_header` hook?